# How to load implicit namespace package by adding the package egg to sys.path?

Tags: python, sys.path, namespace-package

Since python 3.3, [implicit namespace packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) are supported, so that I can have two packages:

```
a
├── b
    ├── __init__.py

a
├── c
    ├── __init__.py
```

and import `a.b` and `a.c` without problems. But it seems that I can only do it with `pip install`; if I only create an egg of either package and add the egg path into `sys.path`, the module cannot be loaded:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./a-b.egg')

import a.b # ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a.b'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [three ways](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/) to create namespace packages:

1. native namespace packages
2. pkgutil-style namespace packages
3. pkg_resources-style namespace packages

The former two are not zip-safe, and that's why the egg doesn't work. The third one is zip-safe.

Basically, the `__init__.py` file for the namespace package needs to contain only the following:

```
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

and every distribution must provide the namespace_packages argument to setup() in setup.py:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='mynamespace-subpackage-a',
    ...
    packages=find_packages()
    namespace_packages=['mynamespace']
)
```